# unable to install ui-grid-auto-fit-columns for Angularjs 1.6 project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, npm, ui-grid

I am working with Angularjs 1.6 and ui-grid 4.4.2 and I hit a snag. I need my grid column widths to expand to the widest content in the column. I found an NPM Package that does this but I am unable to install it.

When I include the package in my angular module I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 5014, column 9 in http://localhost:29236/Scripts/angular.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module CRNApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.grid.autoFitColumns due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.grid.autoFitColumns' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Part of my Angular definition:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('CRNApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.autoFitColumns', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui.grid.emptyBaseLayer', 'ui.grid.selection', 'toaster','ngAnimate']);

    MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', '$log', 'uiGridConstants', '$rootScope','toaster'];

    angular.module('CRNApp')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);
```

The installation instructions are at https://github.com/Den-dp/ui-grid-auto-fit-columns

The install command is: npm install ui-grid-auto-fit-columns -S

After I typed int he NPM install command I saw a new set of folders appear:
[image]

I am inexperienced with Angularjs and NPM so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to import the .js file in my bundleconfig.cs file.